# How to display a contextual menu on a shape?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to display a menu on a shape (cercle,rectangle,polygon) by right-clicking and select and execute a function (change color, ...) on it.
1) I begin by defining an event to my shape:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myShape, 'rightclick', function(event) {...}
```

2) then I define a div and create the menu:

```
myMenu = document.createElement("div");
myMenu.className  = 'contextmenu';
myMenu.innerHTML = "<a id='menu1'>item 1<\/a><a id='menu2'>item 2<\/a>";
```

3) after I must associate this div to my shape:
   I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PROCEED
4) Finally I must display in event.LatLng position the menu:
   I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PROCEED, probably something like so:

```
$('.contextmenu').css('left',x  );
$('.contextmenu').css('top',y );
```

Could you help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't specific on what elements you want to add the context menu so I just added a new circle and did a bit of "quick and dirty" example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Apwr/1/

The trick is here:

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'rightclick', function(event) {
   var pos = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(event.latLng);
   $('#menu').show();
   $('#menu').css("left", pos.x);
   $('#menu').css("top", pos.y);
});
```

For the best results you should really think about creating a new custom overlay ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays ) to draw your context menu. That way it can be reused and the code gets better organized.

Comment: I wrote "on a shape", that means any shapes ! Shall I understand there is no global solution ?

Comment: I check your example on my map: the menu can be displayed out of the map !?

Comment: I checked with a rectangle: ok

Comment: I checked with a polygon: ok  it's awesome ! I learned something tonight ;-)

Comment: ok ? yes and no: the menu is not displayed where the mouse is. For a rectangle, for you, it's the nw point; for me its somewhere between sw and se ! the text of the menu is right shifted for me. Any idea for the differences ?

Comment: The menu appears at the point the mouse was clicked, so maybe that's a different problem?